# Inserting an image into mysql with pyqt

Tags: python, mysql, file-io, pyqt, blob

I am working on inserting a local image into a table on my mysql server. I can insert data but when I download it, it isn't a valid jpg.

Here is a sample like what I am using. Am I doing something wrong when I format the data?

```
printFileLoc = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,  caption = 'Open Print', filter = '*.jpg')
with open(printFileLoc,  'r') as f:
    printBin = re.escape(f.read())
newQry = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
qry = "Insert into prints set print = '{0}'".format(printBin)
newQry.exec_(qry)
```

The code completes as expected but the jpg is no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work. From this:

```
qry = "Insert into prints set print = '{0}'".format(printBin)
```

To this:

```
qry = "Insert into prints set print = '0x{0}'".format(printBin)
```